# Typescript App not looking in node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

When I load the app from the root directory of my server the app works. This is not possible in practice because of the pretty urls our application uses. For example `http://www.website.com/modules/worker/person/1/1/1` loading a page with the previous url results in system.js looking in the folder `/modules/worker/person/1/1` rather than a folder based on "/".

The solution is to set `baseURL:"/"` such that the modules are loaded based on the root directory.

The problem with THIS solution is that node modules are not loaded properly, instead of looking in the node_modules directory, system.js is looking in the root. system.js looks in `/angular2/http.js` rather than `/node_modules/angular2/http.js`

When I switch from "node" module compilation to "classic" the result is the same.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: I solved the problem by specifying the "paths" setting in System.config for the necessary files.

Comment: Hi @ktamlyn could you add this `System.config` here as an answer. It could be helpful for next developers.

Comment: Agreed, had to wait to answer the question myself by Stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my solution to this problem using the paths property in the System.config object:

```
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        baseURL: "/",
        paths: {
            'modules/worker/*': '/modules/worker/*',
            'angular2/*': '/node_modules/angular2/*',
            'rxjs/*': '/node_modules/rxjs/*',
        },
        packages: {
            modules : {
                worker: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('modules/worker/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

For each asset that was being loaded outside main.js (all external libraries) I had to directly point to them in the paths config property. This list would be different depending on the dependencies of your published Typescript classes.